# GAE: How are task handlers impacting the performance metrics of my app?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine documentation indicates the two following information:

1- App Engine reserves automatic scaling capacity for applications with low latency, where the application responds to requests in less than one second.
(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-handled)

2- App Engine tasks have specific timeouts that depend on the scaling type of the service that's running them. For worker services running in the standard environment:Automatic scaling: task processing must finish in 10 minutes.
(https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers)

For compliance with (1), I'm writing APIs that defer any time-consuming processing to a CloudTask task, which allows my API to respond to all client requests in less that a second and benefit from auto-scaling.

But I also have to write the handlers that will perform the time-consuming processing on request of the Cloudtask service. I also want these handlers to be on GAE, and ideally to also get auto-scaling for these.

I do not see any formal declaration that would allow the GAE service to know whether a given part of my app is a client-facing API or a handler for tasks inserted in Cloudtask. Therefore I do not understand how GAE deals with the two requirements I quoted.

I'm worried that my task handler will deter my app performance metrics and as a result prevent auto-scaling.

Should I deploy these handlers in a different project? But then, how do I get auto scaling for these if they take more than 1 second to perform the task?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official GCP [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview):

> The offloaded task is added to a queue, which persists the task until
> it is successfully executed. The queue can also act as a kind of
> dispatch flow control, based on your initial configuration. You create
> and configure the queue which is then managed by the Cloud Tasks
> service. Once tasks are added, the queue dispatches them and makes
> sure they are reliably processed by your workers. **Complexities
> associated with that process, such as user-facing latency costs,
> server crashes, resource consumption limitations, and retry
> management, are handled by the service.**

---

[**Cloud Tasks queues with App Engine targets**](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview#appe):

> In the case of App Engine targets, the Cloud Tasks service also
> forwards the task request to the worker, located within App Engine,
> based on how the task (or, less commonly, the queue itself) is
> configured. These queues dispatch requests at a reliable, configurable
> rate. They guarantee reliable task execution - upon success, all
> workers must send an HTTP response code (200-299) to the Cloud Tasks
> service, in this instance before a deadline based on the instance
> scaling type of the service: 10 minutes for automatic scaling or up to
> 24 hours for manual scaling. If a different response is sent, or no
> response, the task is retried.
>
> **Because the handlers are part of App Engine, the Cloud Tasks service
> itself can do much of the process management for the task, scaling
> workers up and down in relation to traffic and deleting tasks when
> they are completed.**

---

As an option, in order to minimize the latency, you could set different **GAE worker services** which will be responsible for task handling and then [**configure the routing for your tasks queue**](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#routing).